# Jquery AJAX returning empty response on selected values

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

I am trying to cascade update a SELECT tag using jQuery AJAX.
The criterium is passed as POST/JSON to a PHP script which, in turn, pulls the data from a MySql database using PDO. The response is then displayed using JSON. 
My problem is that with 2 specific records, the response will be empty.

**The form** (selectBB.php):

```
<?php
include_once  '../core/classes/bbClasses.php';
$db=new workingDB();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="../Core/css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="../Core/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<title>Liste des départements</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <div id="logoZone"></div>
            <nav>
                <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Positions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Maintenance</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Rapports</a></li>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <aside>
            <ul>
                <li>Reservation</li>
                <li>Location</li>
                <li>Renouvellement</li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
        <div id="content">
    <form method="$POST" name="frmSlctBB">

        <label for="slctDPT">Departement</label>
        <select id= "Dpt" name="slctDPT">
            <?php
            $listDPT=$db->loadDPT();
            if(count($listDPT)){
                foreach ($listDPT as $DPT) {
                    echo ("<option value=".$DPT['IDDepartment'].">".$DPT['DepartmentName']."</option>");
                }
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <label for ="slctVille">Ville</label>
        <select id="slctVille" name="slctVille">


        </select>
        <label for ="slctFormat">Format</label>
        <select id="slctFormat" name="slctFormat"></select>
        <label for ="slctStatut">Statut</label>
        <select id="slctStatut" name="Statut"></select>
</form>
            <!--Error log-->
            <div class="errorlog"></div>
            <!-- End of error log-->

</div> <!-- end of content--> 
<footer>
    <ul>
        <li> <address><strong>Dauphin s.a.</strong>bldg #8, complexe Acra <br>route de Delmas,<br>Delmas, HT6120<br>Haiti</address></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
</div> <!-- end of wrapper-->

    <script src="../Core/js/searchCritFunctions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#Dpt").change(function(){
                fetchCities();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**AJAX request**

```
function fetchCities(){
// Uses Ajax to return a list of cities based on selected department
var selDpt= $("#Dpt").val();
$(".errorlog").empty();

$.ajax({
    url :'listCities.php',
    data:{d:selDpt},
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON'
})
.done( function(result){
    // Clear Select from previous entries
    $('#slctVille').empty();
    //load new entries
    for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
        $('#slctVille').append('<option value='+ result[i].IDCity +'>'+result[i].CityName+'</option>');
    };
    console.log(result);
})
.fail(function (){
    $(document).ajaxError(function(jqXHR,textStatus,thrownError){
        $(".errorlog").append("<h3>An error has occured</h3><p>"+textStatus+"</p>");
        console.log(thrownError);

        })
    ;


});
    };
```

**PDO Statement**

```
<?php

require_once '../core/config/config.php';

class workingDB extends db {

public function loadDPT(){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM tblDepartments ORDER BY DepartmentName";
    $q =  $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute();
    return $row=$q -> fetchAll();
}
public function loadCities($dpt){
    $sql="SELECT IDCity, IDDepartement, CityName FROM tblCities WHERE IDDepartement=".$dpt;
    $q = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute();
    $row=$q -> fetchAll();
    return $row;
    }
}
```

As a tentative to debug the code, I have outputted the response to the console. If, for example, the data sent thru AJAX is "5", the html response would be :

```
    [{"IDCity":"22","0":"22","IDDepartement":"5","1":"5","CityName":"Hinche","2":"Hinche"},{"IDCity":"23","0":"23","IDDepartement":"5","1":"5","CityName":"Mirebalais","2":"Mirebalais"}]
```

On the opposite, if Ajax data is "1" or "9", the response would be empty.

Thanks in advance for your help.

P.S.: I have verified the database and these specific rows aren't empty.

P.S.: @Sean, thanks for noting I had forget to add listCities.php

```
<?php
//Output list of cities based on departments selected
include_once  '../core/classes/bbClasses.php';
$d=$_POST['d'];  //array of departments selected
$base= new workingDB();
$villes=$base ->loadCities($d);
echo json_encode($villes);
$base="";
?>
```

Comment: What does `listCities.php` look like?

Comment: I have added to the question for clarity.Thanks.

Comment: There is something amiss, as you say that with `the data sent thru AJAX is "2"`, you get `[{"IDCity":"22","0":"22","IDDepartement":"5","1":"5",...`, but since your query is `SELECT IDCity, IDDepartement, CityName FROM tblCities WHERE IDDepartement=".$dpt;` you should be getting `IDDepartement":"2"` not `IDDepartement":"5"`. So somewhere in `data:{d:selDpt},`, `$d=$_POST['d'];`, `$villes=$base ->loadCities($d);`,`public function loadCities($dpt)`, `WHERE IDDepartement=".$dpt` your value changed from 2 -> 5.

Comment: @Sean, I guess it was a typo from me, i made the correction in the original post. But Following your remark, I noticed that when I set the criterium to "3", the Firefox console will output
 [Object { 0="16", 1="3", 2="Jacmel", more...}, Object { 0="17", 1="3", 2="Marigot", more...}]
but when I set it to "9", I will get
Object { url="listCities.php", type="POST", isLocal=false, more...}

Comment: Based on the console output you get from when it is `9`, your ajax if failing as you are seeing the `console.log(thrownError);` from `$(document).ajaxError(function(jqXHR,textStatus,thrownError){`. I assume `1` is the first value, and `9` is the last value in your select? It may not change anything, but try putting quotes around your select values `echo ("<option value='".$DPT['IDDepartment']."'>".$DPT['DepartmentName']."</option>");`

Comment: Unfortunately, addind the quotes doesn't solve the issue. Also, the values go from 1 to 10. I checked the Select statement directly in phpMyAdmin and it works just fine